# Dynamically generated textarea (JQuery) to fit inital content size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically create, already filled, textarea using JQuery. I have a problem with making it's height to fit the content of given 'question'. Does someone have an idea how to solve it? I would be grateful.

```
questionHolder = document.createElement("textarea");
questionHolder.value = question;
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can set your textarea to 100% in the css `#container>textarea { height:100% }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Textarea` has a `rows` attribute. Try searching for it.

```
question.setAttribute('rows','5')
```

Comment: Ooo! It's nice, thanks I'll try to do something with it :)